# JSTL - Display content on specific week day

Tags: jsp, jstl, dayofweek, weekday

I am currently using the following code to display some content on the 30th of November 2012:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>
<fmt:formatDate var="currentDate" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd" />

<%
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
String a = sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
%>

<c:if test='${currentDate ge "2012.11.26" && currentDate le "2012.11.30"}'>It is the 30th of November 2012</c:if>
```

Is there a way I can do this with the day of the week, for instance every Monday display a block of promotional text, that would disappear the rest of the week?

Also, if i add the below code, I can see that it prints the following 'Mon Mar 11 14:54:33 GMT 2013'.

```
<c:out value="${now}" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>
<c:if test="${fn:startsWith(now, 'Mon')}" >
     It is Monday.
</c:if>
```